# Installation error for openfire in ubuntu

Tags: openfire

I am trying to install openfire on ubuntu server but after installation I am not able to open it on `http://mydomain:9090/setup/index.jsp` . After installation i got the message

> "Starting openfire: openfire."

I have followed the following steps.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk*
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
>
> java -version
>
> cd /tmp wget -O openfire_3.9.3_all.deb
>   http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire_3.9.3_all.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i openfire_3.9.3_all.deb

Openfire is not activated yet. Then I check with

```
netstat -ntulp
```

Output:

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8749            0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 :::55880                :::*                                -